# How to pass an object using $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, callback, angularjs-scope

I have one function named as saveInDB. Which saves data in the Database. Object is passed as a parameter to the function.

```
$scope.SaveDB(iObj,function(iResult){
//after a sucessfull opreation in the DB. Now  I need iObj to be passed to other controller.
// I have used $emit method
$rootScope.$emit('saveCallback');
})
```

In other controller where I need to access the iObj to other controllers. I am not getting the object. In a controllers I have

```
var _save = $rootScope.$on('saveCallback',function(){
//i want same obj(which is used for saving ) to be access here.
})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1) If your controllers are parent-child, and you're emitting the event from the child controller**, you just need to $emit the event and the parent controller just uses $on to listen to it.

Emitting event from child controller:

```
$scope.SaveDB(iObj,function(iResult){
  $scope.$emit('saveCallback',iResult); //pass the data as the second parameter
});
```

Listening to the event (in parent controller):

```
$scope.$on('saveCallback',function(event,iResult){//receive the data as second parameter

});
```

**2) If your controllers are siblings**

*From your controller*, you `$emit` the event to the parent's scope.

```
$scope.SaveDB(iObj,function(iResult){

   $scope.$emit('saveCallback',iResult);
});
```

Your parent's scope then listens to this event and `$broadcast` it to its children. This method could be written inside angular module's `.run` block

```
$scope.$on('saveCallback',function (event,iresult){
    $scope.$broadcast('saveCallback',iresult);
});
```

*Or you can inject the $rootScope to the controller and have it $broadcast the event:*

```
$scope.SaveDB(iObj,function(iResult){
   $rootScope.$broadcast('saveCallback',iResult);
});
```

The scopes interested in the event can subscribe to it:

```
$scope.$on('saveCallBack',function(event, data) {
   //access data here 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('saveCallback',iresult);
```

and where you want to catch

```
$scope.$on('saveCallBack',function(event, data) {
   //access data here 
});
```