# How can I get data from controller to directive when I click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send the data to directive link function from controller when i used `ng-clicked`, but I failed to send the data to directive, the directive is calling when the page was loading at first time

### here is my html code

```
 <h2 ng-click="clickMe(somedata)"> click </h2>

    <my-directive my-key="myVal"> </my-directive>
```

### here is my controller

```
.controller('myController',function($scope){

$scope.clickMe=function(somedata){
$scope.myVal=somedata;
};

});
```

### my directive

```
.directive('myDirective',function(){
return{
  restrict:'E',
  scope:{
    myKey:'='
        },
  templateUrl:'exampleTempl.html',
  controller:'myController',
  link:function(scope,elem,attr){
   console.log(scope.myKey); // getting undefined
   console.log(scope.myVal); //here i want the data from controller when i clicked on ng-click
  }
}
});
```

Comment: can you share exampleTempl.html.html?

Comment: use $rootscope instead scope hope it'll work take a look at [this](http://jsbin.com/bequy/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass data through **services** or you can use `$rootScope` for that, but using root scope is bad practice. So, use services. There should be more ways to do that, but services are pretty good.

Here is the clear example for passing data via services: [AngularJS Service Passing Data Between Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952620/angularjs-service-passing-data-between-controllers)

And another one for $rootScope: [How to pass an object using $rootScope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346565/how-to-pass-an-object-using-rootscope)

**Updated:**

You can also pass data through **parent-child** controllers via `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$broadcast`, but remember, it's true only for parent-child controllers.

But you can do the same things with `$rootScope` like `$rootScope.$emit` and `$rootScope.$broadcast`. If you will use it, it doesn't matter anymore, how controllers relate to each other (this is true for "brothers" controllers too).

This article should help you: https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: can you please give me an example using `$rootScope` and by using `services` @Commercial Suicide

Answer (score 2):

I hope it works for you;

```
.directive('myDirective',function(){
return{
  restrict:'E',
  scope:{
    myKey:'=bindingmyVal'
        },
  templateUrl:'exampleTempl.html',
  controller:'myController',
  link:function(scope,elem,attr){
   console.log(scope.myKey); //here i want the data from controller when i clicked on ng-click
  }
}
});
```

Comment: it is showing `undefined` on loading the directive not getting the data @kemal akoglu

Answer (score 1):

Since the controller is inside the directive on an isolate scope, its functions are not available to the parent scope. Set the variable directly:

```
<!-- REPLACE 
<h2 ng-click="clickMe(somedata)"> click </h2>
-->
<!-- WITH -->
<h2 ng-click="myVal = somedata"> click </h2>

<my-directive my-key="myVal"> </my-directive>
```

In the directive controller use the `$onChanges` [Life-Cycle Hook<sup>1</sup>](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

```
directiveApp.controller('myController',function(){

    this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.myKey) {
            var val = changesObj.myKey.currentValue;
            console.log(val);
        };
    };  
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

Comment: This is the simplest answer in this case. +1